# Disable numericTextBox onClick radio button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have radio button and numericTextBox. I want when radio button ="y" the numericTextBox will not disable. I'm currently trying but not working well. I'm using `onClick="consign()"` here. Is it I'm missing something?

**HTML :**

```
<div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="consignment">Consignment</label>
                </div><div>
                <input class="k-radio" id="yes3" name="consignment" type="radio" value="y" onClick="consign()" data-bind="checked:consignment">
                <label class="k-radio-label" for="yes3">Yes</label>
                <input class="k-radio" id="no3" name="consignment" type="radio" value="n" data-bind="checked:consignment">
                <label class="k-radio-label" for="no3" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-right:20px;">No</label>

                <label for="marginConsignment">Margin to supplier</label>
                <input style="margin-left: 5px;"  id="margin" data-role="numerictextbox" data-bind="value: marginConsignment">
            </div>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function consign() {
var radiobtn = document.getElementById("yes3").value;
if(radiobtn == "y"){
  $("#margin").prop("disabled", false); 
} else if (radiobtn == "n"){
    $("#margin").prop("disabled", true);
}  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this logic, I've done it without jquery:

```js
function consign(e) {
  var radiobtn = e.value;
  if(radiobtn == "y"){
    document.getElementById("margin").removeAttribute('disabled'); 
  } else if (radiobtn == "n"){
      document.getElementById("margin").setAttribute('disabled', true); 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="k-edit-label">
                <label for="consignment">Consignment</label>
                </div><div>
                <input class="k-radio" id="yes3" name="consignment" type="radio" value="y" onClick="consign(this)" data-bind="checked:consignment">
                <label class="k-radio-label" for="yes3">Yes</label>
                <input class="k-radio" id="no3" name="consignment" type="radio" value="n" onClick="consign(this)" data-bind="checked:consignment">
                <label class="k-radio-label" for="no3" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-right:20px;">No</label>

                <label for="marginConsignment">Margin to supplier</label>
                <input style="margin-left: 5px;"  id="margin" data-role="numerictextbox" data-bind="value: marginConsignment">
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*radiobtn* has always the same value: y, it never gets on *else* condition

```
var radiobtn = document.getElementById("yes3").value;
```

Try this, and remove onClick="consign()"
 from your inputs

```
$('input[name=consignment]').change(function(){
  if ($(this).val() === "y") {
    $("#margin").prop("disabled", false); 
  } else if ($(this).val() === "n") {
    $("#margin").prop("disabled", true);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="k-edit-label">
            <label for="consignment">Consignment</label>
            </div><div>
            <input class="k-radio" id="yes3" name="consignment" type="radio" onClick="consign()" data-bind="checked:consignment">
            <label class="k-radio-label" for="yes3">Yes</label>
            <input class="k-radio" id="no3" onClick="consign()" name="consignment" type="radio" data-bind="checked:consignment">
            <label class="k-radio-label" for="no3" style="margin-left: 30px; margin-right:20px;">No</label>

            <label for="marginConsignment">Margin to supplier</label>
            <input style="margin-left: 5px;"  id="margin" data-role="numerictextbox" data-bind="value: marginConsignment">
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
    function consign() {
  document.getElementById("margin").disabled = document.getElementById("yes3").checked;
}
```